# How to prevent CALL_STATE_IDLE detection on app starts?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

The app listens for incoming call and then stops playing music. Then, I want music to restart after the call ends. But I am having a problem with `CALL_STATE_IDLE` as it **gets detected on app starts** so any call inside its method is being invoked on app starts.

My code look like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ...
    listenForIncomingCall();
   ...
   }
    private void listenForIncomingCall() {
    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Incoming call: Pause music
                //stop playing music
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not in call: Play music

            //a code placed here activates on app starts

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mgr != null)

    {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

How can I prevent this? How can I register some listener if not in `onCreate`?

Comment: Ignore CALL_STATE_IDLE if your app hasn't paused playback.

Comment: @Michael Like in the code I posted, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a supstitute solution. Feel free to use it. In case someone has a better one, feel free to share it with the community.

```
private void listenForIncomingCall() {
    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        boolean toTrack = false; //to prevent triggering in onCreate

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Incoming call: Pause music
                doSomething();
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not in call: Play music
                if (toTrack) {
                    doSomething();
                }
                toTrack = true;
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                if (toTrack) {
                    doSomething();
                }
                toTrack = true;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mgr != null)

    {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What it's mean by `doSomething();` can you replace it with `pause()` or `start();` methods. I am getting same problem after completion of call if I call `pause()` in `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` and `start();` in `CALL_STATE_IDLE`